# makemigrationsをした時のKeyError: ('　', '　')が解決できない

Tags: python, python3, django

python3,Djangoでwebシステムを開発しています。

ローカルで動作を確認後、リモートのサーバーへデプロイするという方法で開発しております。

modelクラスに変更があった場合は、リモートのサーバーでmakemigratinons, migrateが必要になりますが、makemigrationsを行う際に、以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

```
KeyError: ('admin_csv', 'prefcityno')
```

このエラーについて調べると、'admin_csv'に関係する中で、'prefcityno'がみつからないというような内容と思います。

考えられる原因は、ローカル環境とリモート環境での、makemigrationsと、maigrateの実行に仕方だと思っています。
ローカル環境では、希望する動きになるまでmakemigratinsとmigrateを何度か繰り返し、動作を確認した後に、リモートへデプロイして、makemigratinsした作成したファイルが、5〜6個ある中で、1度だけmigrateしました。

コンフリクトしているとエラーが出たため対応したのですが、その内容が悪かったのかと思います。関係しそうなファイル（0001_initial.py等）を削除してから、マージ等をしました。

その後、リモートのデータベースのテーブルを削除して、migrationsのファイルを削除してから、makemigratinsしても、KeyError: ('admin_csv', 'prefcityno')が発生してしまう状況です。

'admin_csv'は、変更を加えてエラーがでるmodels.pyを含むappディレクトリです。
'prefcityno'は、ローカル環境で開発中に使用してた名前で、最終的にデプロイしたコードには含まれていません。

だいぶ深い所でのエラーなのではないかと心配しています。
今回のエラーの解決策について、ご教授いただきないでしょうか？

ファイル等の階層は以下のとおりです。

```
project
-- accounts
-- admin_csv
---- migrations
---- __init__.py
---- admin.py
---- apps.py
---- models.py
---- tests.py
---- views.py
-- project
-- app
-- static
-- manage.py
env
```

`$ python3 manage.py makemigrations` 後のエラーメッセージの詳細は以下のとおりです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 141, in handle
    loader.project_state(),
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 324, in project_state
    return self.graph.make_state(nodes=nodes, at_end=at_end, real_apps=list(self.unmigrated_apps))
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 315, in make_state
    project_state = self.nodes[node].mutate_state(project_state, preserve=False)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 87, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 256, in state_forwards
    state.remove_model(app_label, self.name_lower)
  File "/home/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 99, in remove_model
    del self.models[app_label, model_name]
KeyError: ('admin_csv', 'prefcityno')
```

実行環境
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 2.2.2
PostgreSQL:12.1

Comment: エラーが消えて、makemigrationsができました。原因はリモートのサーバーに過去のmigrationsのファイルが残っていた事です。ローカルのプロジェクトで削除してデプロイしており、そのままの構成になっているかと思っていましたが、過去のファイルの場合、手作業での削除が必要でした。イージーミスで質問してしまい、すみません。

Answer (score 1):

エラーが消えて `makemigrations` ができました。原因はリモートのサーバーに過去の `migrations` のファイルが残っていた事です。

ローカルのプロジェクトで削除してデプロイしており、そのままの構成になっているかと思っていましたが、過去のファイルの場合、手作業での削除が必要でした。

---

*この投稿は [@tio さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62092/makemigrations%e3%82%92%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%99%82%e3%81%aekeyerror-%e3%81%8c%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment67753_62092) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*